# svn: Error processing command 'modify-wcprop'

Tags: linux, svn

I am getting below error while performing any svn action like svn update, svn cleanup, svn switch etc on my branch.

```
svn: In directory '<directory path>'
svn: Error processing command 'modify-wcprop' in '<directory path>'
svn: Failed to load properties from disk
svn: Malformed file
```

What is this error all about and how can I work my branch as expected?

Comment: Maybe your working copy is corrupt. Are you able to delete it and check out a new one?

Comment: I am able to delete it but not able to checking it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can help if you have working copy in format version prior to 12.

Try to rename your `<directory path>` to something, then update your working copy (`svn up`).

Reapply changes from backed-up `<directory path>` manually (if any).